# Select data that exists in A but not in B

Tags: sql, select, join, left-join, exists

Imagine I have this tables:
[image: this tables].

What I need is to get the Data that exists in A but not in B, in this case my SELECT will have to return "2".

I've done it before, but right know I can't remember how. I suppose it was something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A as a
LEFT JOIN B AS b ON b.column = a.column
```

But it's not working. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're just missing a filter:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A as a
LEFT JOIN B AS b ON b.column = a.column
WHERE B.column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

If `B` could have multiple rows that match `A`, then this query would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM B WHERE b.column = a.column)
```

Answer (score 5):

the following should work for most database types

```
select *
from A
where A.column not in (select column from B)
```